# Why aapt2 generate compile error "Check failed"?

Tags: android, command-line, android-resources, aapt2

I'm running AAPT2 from the command line:

```
%PATH_AAPT2%\aapt2.exe compile -v --dir res -o build
```

Many resource files are compiled. But after a time aapt2 is aborting with the message

```
Check failed: node_stack.size() == 1u
```

The build output is:

```
>C:\Android\aapt2\aapt2.exe compile -v --dir res -o build
res\color\button_back.xml: note: compiling XML.
...
res\drawable\rectangle.xml: note: compiling XML.
res\drawable\row.xml: note: compiling XML.
res\drawable\splash_screen.xml: note: compiling XML.
res\menu\menu_main.xml: note: compiling XML.
aapt2.exe F 08-23 07:52:20 16152 15008 ResourceParser.cpp:346] Check failed: node_stack.size() == 1u
```

What is the reason?

The used AAPT2 version is [4.1.0 rc01](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.1.0-rc01-6503028/aapt2-4.1.0-rc01-6503028-windows.jar), but the error occurs with other versions too.

The error seems not to be related to any resource. I removed the recently compiled resources like menu_main.xml, but the error occurs furthermore.

Comment: can you check for traces in build output? or can you run assembleDebug form right side of Gtadle option : Tasks -> build ->assembleDebug

Comment: @notTdar, gradle is not used, that's a pure command-line usage

Comment: It seems to say that there's something wrong with the nodes. Can you post the content of the menu_main.xml?

Comment: Try re-running the original `aapt2` command with `-v`; `aapt2 compile -v --dir ... -o ...`